# python repeating regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex pattern like this

```
(\w)(..\1..\1|...\1...\1|....\1....\1|.....\1.....1)
```

I want to make it shorter. As we can see the number of dots is from 2 to 5. I want to write something like `(\w)(.{2,5}\1){2}` but in this case it will match some wrong strings `q00q000q`. Also I can try to use number reference but it repeats chars from a string instead of symbols `.`. Is it possible to repeat pattern `.{2,5}` as a specific count of `.`?

UPDATE
It was a challange about tic-tac-toe game. I needed to write down a regexp of length <=50 which can be used to find out if somebody wins

Comment: In other words I need a reg exp for string like that
QaaaQaaaQaaaQ (count of letter 'a' doesn't specified)

Comment: I think you need to escape the '.'. As in `\.`.

Comment: @MattCremeens Nope, otherwise you will match a literal dot.

Comment: I don't need to escape dots I need them as 'any char'
valid string also could be like that 'QaaaQavcQ'

Comment: @HamZa, then I misunderstood the question. :(

Comment: @Leo I don't think it's feasible. Not with a simple regex at least. You would need to "count" the dots and keep state. I don't know of any feature within python regex that can do this.

Comment: If I may ask, *why* do you want to make it shorter? Knowing that might help us to suggest alternatives.

Comment: not possible. what you want is a classical example of non-regular language. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language. it describes that regular expression is not capable of remembering how many characters it counted

Comment: @Fabricator thanks, you are right I need to find another way.
 it is not a real-life task, just a challange so I have a length limit on regexp I can use

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the regex with a Python expression:

```
In [13]: r'(\w)(%s)'%'|'.join(r'{dots}\1{dots}\1'.format(dots='.'*i) for i in range(2,6))
Out[13]: '(\\w)(..\\1..\\1|...\\1...\\1|....\\1....\\1|.....\\1.....\\1)'
```

Comment: Cool but we're back to square one :)

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. If OP's problem is "my regex is 16K characters long and I don't want to type it by hand", then my solution helps. If OP's problem is "I want to discover a cool new feature of regex", then I didn't help him at all.